# Comparing words in list with words in frequency list using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary, frequency

I have 2 frequency lists with thousands of elements whilst I also have 2 smaller lists with few elements. The idea is that I need to check how many times each element of my smaller list appears in the frequency lists, and to compare them, and to finally display my findings in a table using pandas package.

*Frequency lists:*

```
pos_freqdist = FreqDist(get_all_words(pos_train))
neg_freqdist = FreqDist(get_all_words(neg_train))
```

This is what pos_freqdist prints as it stands (It doesn't simply print all of the positive words, but counts the frequency of words of which are contained within positive reviews):

```
FreqDist({'the': 6737, '.': 6513, ',': 6357, 'and': 3952, 'a': 3441, 'of': 3268, 'to': 2980, 'is': 2645, 'I': 2068, 'in': 1956, ...})
```

And I also have 2 smaller lists of which contain few sentiment words:

```
my_positive_word_list
my_negative_word_list
```

I am checking the positive/negative sentiment of these words in thousands of reviews that I have already classified as positive and negative.

Does the frequency list actually count as a dictionary? Tuples? I'm not sure.

Comment: it can be convert to dict using `dict(pos_freqdist) `

Comment: Though how do I count how many times each element in my list occurs in the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the frequency list just like a normal dictionary.
Internally it has a dictionary kind of structure for faster access
That is why you can do `pos_freqdist['the']` and it prints **6737**

Comment: Though how do I count how many times each element in my list occurs in the dictionary?

Comment: you can do something like this: 
pos_freqdist[my_positive_word_list[word_index]]
That will display the frequency in pos_freqdist of the word with index word_index

Comment: Must I check one index at a time?

Comment: you do need to check one at a time